# How to keep the original html and use React on the page

Tags: html, reactjs

Please see the pic. I have a web page with complicated HTML,
which is about 80% of the page. 20% of the page will be React components.

Now how do I inject those components and keep 80% of the page intact?
I want to keep those 80% in html format, since it is often updated by other people who know html very well and don't want to learn any JSX.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You'd use `ReactDOM.render()` to render your React component(s) in those 2 container DIVs.